# Webpack: ts-loader generates d.ts file in output directory but not js file

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, tsc, ts-loader

I could generate .d.ts file for corresponding typescript file using webpack but not javascript file (.js). `tsc` command generates js and .d.ts file for corresponding typescript file. But I want to use webpack for some specific reason. I feel reason why webpack cannot generate .js file is because webpack uses loader such ts-loader to compile typescript file which generate js and d.ts file. It keeps this d.ts file in an output directory but webpack compiles all js file and form bundle.js file. I even tried using other loaders. Can anyone suggest me way to get js file after compiling in an output directory?

Comment: Since you basically reposted your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67175861/unable-to-generate-javascript-js-file-for-corresponding-typescript-file-using) which you deleted immediately after I pointed you to a dupe target, please _read_ the answer on the dupe target this time.

Comment: @Cerbrus,Your duplicate question is not answering my question. So there was a option of asking new question so I asked new question. Why don't you understand my question is different from duplicate question that is marked. I swear I tried your answer it didn't work. Otherwise, tell me why would I post the question again. Why are you so mean to me?

Comment: On the question you deleted you didn't even give me a chance to re-open the question, you just immediately deleted it after stating it's not about bundling... I'm not being "mean", I'm trying to help you.

Comment: Okay... I'll give you benefit of doubt. Note: You marked this question as duplicate. But I don't care as long as someone is helping and I'll be grateful to you. So when I run tsc command, tsc command generate .js and .d.ts file. Same way, I am trying with Webpack. But in webpack, it does generate .d.ts file but it compiles .js files and create a single bundle file. I have no issue with single bundle file but I also want those compile .js file. Do you know any way I could do it?

Comment: And the commands listed in the dupe answer don't work? Are you getting any errors? Also, if tsc gives you the desired output, why do you need to use webpack?

Comment: I am sorry say but dupe answer doesn't work. I swear I tried. I am not getting any error because it successfully compile. I want to use webpack  because while building I am using tsc && webpack command. Since webpack does the partial work which I needed. Instead of using tsc && webpack while building I want to use webpack only. I came across ts-loader and other loaders too but none of them gives output like tsc.

Comment: I see. Well, I don't know how else I can help there, then, but you might want to consider that using `tsc` might be the only option.

Comment: Even I don't think anybody is going to answer my question. You were the only one to reply so thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old ticket, but I think this is related to the `tsconfig.json` file. If you have:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
  }
}
```

you may expect to see a bunch of `*.d.ts` files appear.